# Strava API - accurate longitude and latitude

Tags: api, strava

Does anyone know a way to get the exact longitude and latitude for an activity from the strava api using a get request?

I'm trying to integrate the strava api with google maps and I'm trying to build an array with the appropriate long/lat locations, but the `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?per_page=100...` request is only returning longitude and latitudes rounded off like: `start_longitude: 2.6`.

I've found a "hacky" way of retrieving the start coordinates by looping through results and then sending off another request within the loop, although this is sending WAY too many requests. - below is a snippet of my request:

```
// start request
$.get( "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?per_page=100&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN", function (results) {

    // loop through request
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        if(results[i].type === 'Run') {
            // add an element to the array for each result
            stravaComplete.push(true);

            $.get( "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/"+ results[i].id +"?per_page=5&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN", function (runs) {
                 if(typeof runs.segment_efforts[0] != "undefined"){
                    var runLatitude = runs.segment_efforts[0].segment.start_latitude;
                    var runLongitude = runs.segment_efforts[0].segment.start_longitude;
                    stravaActivityList.push({"lat": runLatitude, "lng": runLongitude});
                 }

                 // remove the element from the array
                 stravaComplete.pop();

                 // if all the elements have been removed from the array it means the request is complete
                if(stravaComplete.length == 0) {
                    // reinitialize map
                    initMap(stravaActivityList);
                }
             });
        }
    }

});
```

Any guidance would be great. Thanks.

Comment: So, the coords returned from `/activities` are less precise than those returned from `/activities/:id`?

Comment: @MattMorgan I'm currently retrieving the lng/lat from the 'segments' element within activities/id (they are not rounded off so I can get an approx location - which is better than what I can retrieve from /activities) although they are nowhere near accurate enough, as I'd like to show the whole route in google maps

Comment: Hmm...that sounds like it could be a limitation of the API.  Have you tried asking this question on Strava's dev forum, or hitting up their support folks?  I mean, if they're not exposing the data, there's not much you can do.  Not to pass the buck, but that's where I'd ask.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you need coordinates of start points only, or for the whole activity and what accuracy is required.

Response to query `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities` includes a field `map => summary_polyline` from which you should be able to extract coordinates of the whole (although simplified) activity. You can also use this polyline to display it in google maps.

If you, however, need even better accuracy you need to retrieve every activity and use `map => summary_polyline` or `map => polyline` fields.

To get full data [streams](https://strava.github.io/api/v3/streams/) should be used

Answer (score 0):

Use `summary_polyline[0]` and `summary_polyline[-1]` (Ruby) instead of rounded values. See [this code](https://github.com/dblock/slack-strava/blob/master/slack-strava/models/map.rb) from [Slava](https://slava.playplay.io/) for an example.